# get the Alarm object of CloudWatch using boto 2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I created an alarm and want to delete it afterward... 
The [documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html) for boto 2 doesn't show how to do that.

Any help ? 
Thanks

Comment: do you know the name of the alarm?

Comment: Yes. Suppose it s called 'termination_alarm'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete alarms, the API you need is `DeleteAlarms`. The link you have in your question is mentioning it (search for `delete_alarms`).

Also, boto 3 is the recommended version to use and here is the API you need: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.delete_alarms

Example of how to do it with Boto 3:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
client.delete_alarms(AlarmNames=['SomeAlarmName'])
```

Boto 2 example:

```
import boto
client = boto.connect_cloudwatch()
client.delete_alarms('SomeAlarmName')
```

If you don't know the name, you can get a list of alarms with (the same for boto 2 and 3):

```
client.describe_alarms()
```

Comment: You need to get the object of the alarm to delete it using delete_alarms . How do you get the object by the name of the alarm. It is not mention in the doc.

Comment: You only need the name, I update the answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Boto3. But if you are tied to Boto2, then:

```
import boto
cw = boto.connect_cloudwatch()
alarms= cw.describe_alarms()
for alarm in alarms:
  print alarm.name
```

Check if the alarm you want to delete is listed. Then use that name:

```
cw.delete_alarms([<alarm_to_be_deleted>])
```